# BT_GET_CAPABILITIES warning slowing down audio apps

Tags: sound, bluetooth, alsa, lirc, audacity

I'm using a bluetooth audio receiver to stream music from my PC to an old stereo.
Everything works fine, except that everytime an app needs to use audio, and starts initializing ALSA, it gets lots of warnings like this:

```
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

I know it's safe to ignore them, but it takes about 20 seconds to initialize audio because of this. For instance, Audacity takes too long to open, and crashes eventually by this. And there are also some apps that show a timeout error and I just can't use them if I have bluetooth turned on.

I tried googling it and there seems to be a bug filled with bluez-alsa but couldn't get more info than that.

Any workaround suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the application, it might be possible to disable ALSA support so that it instead uses Pulseaudio directly.

For example I have an OpenAL game which shows this problem. I edited `/etc/openal/alsoft.conf` and added the line `drivers = pulse`, so that OpenAL will always use Pulseaudio rather than checking for ALSA, OSS or other audio frameworks. Since it appears to be the ALSA framework which causes the BT_GET_CAPABILITIES error, this change fixed the problem for me.